# Regex for the words containing at least one numeric value?

Tags: regex, eclipse

As part of my assignment I have to replace words with at least one numeric with the word STOP, Is there any way of doing it using regex?

> **Words**
>
>   a1wew
>   abc
>   1rr
>   sd
>
> **Output**
>   
>   STOP
>   
>   abc
>   STOP
>   
>   sd

I am using regex of eclipse in find.

Comment: Sounds pretty simple. What did you try? What about words that begin with a digit - how would you do that? What about words that end with a digit?

Comment: Ok so according to you write one regex for word having numeric at the start, one at the end, on in the middle. @Kobi I was trying to this in one single regex hence could not do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible regex is grep '.*[0-9].*'

Answer (score 1):

Find:

```
(?=.*\d)\w+
```

Replace:

```
STOP
```